# What to do with API keys if our project is open-source?

Tags: discussion, api-key

Is it OK to share the key in our source? Someone could just pick it up and use it for other purposes.

Comment: Couldn't you just require that they get their own keys?

Comment: @Cyclone I think that beats the purpose of having keys in the first place..

Comment: Raffi Krikorian of Twitter isn't convinced that [requiring each end user to register for his own key](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/twitter-development-talk/wWxy5pHHcxI/82f-yLONS_UJ) "beats the purpose".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry too much about leaking your key.  Its not the end of the world.

Remember, throttling and bans are done based on IP.  The key is basically for identification purposes.

Only in cases where the vast majority of the users of a key are abusive would we consider banning the key itself.

Comment: And of course, in that case, it's likely because the app was poorly designed or is inherently malicious.